# How to make a variable contain a string from a dictionary via input

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

Im making an AI/Chat Bot from scratch and I want to make code where the bot uses dictionaries of its known stuff and uses them to talk to the user. However, when I try to make the answer appear on the screen using a variable, an error appears

Ive tried making the code so that when the user writes down something in the greetings dictionary, the bot will say "Hello!". But when i run the code, this error comes up: 'set' object is not callable' on line 7 of the code.

```
MY_NAME = input("What is my name? \n")

Greeting = {"Hi", "Hello", "Hey"}

while True:
    input = input("Talk to " + MY_NAME + "\n")
    if input == Greeting():
        print ("Hello!")
```

I want the fixed code to this. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems**:

- `Greeting` is a set. You use it like calling a function which results in your error.
- Change variable `input` because it conflicts with the original `input` function. In the next iteration, it will throw error as *"str object is not callable"*.

You need a membership check:

```
while True:
    inp = input("Talk to " + MY_NAME + "\n")
    if inp in Greeting:
        print ("Hello!")
```

Comment: Still its the same as mine tho\

Comment: So i've done this. But now it comes up with the error ''str' object is not callable' on the line before. How do i fix that?

Comment: Oh whoops. I feel dumb now. I fixed it. Thankyou for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `in`, and rename `input` to `inp` since `input` will override the default `input` keyword:

```
MY_NAME = input("What is my name? \n")

Greeting = {"Hi", "Hello", "Hey"}

while True:
    inp = input("Talk to " + MY_NAME + "\n")
    if inp in Greeting:
        print ("Hello!")
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't see your answer posted before. I'm sure you won't take that serious.

Comment: Thankyou for this answer too!